# Ruby on OSX how to execute file with default application

Tags: ruby, macos

I've got a Ruby script bundled as an OSX .app
how do I for example open an image file bundled in the apps resources
with the default app (preview). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to open a file with the associated program is different from one operating system (or shell) to another.  Here are 4 examples that will work on the specified OSes:

### Mac OS X

Use the standard `open` command:

```
system %{open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

### Windows

Use the standard command shell `start`, available beginning with Windows 95:

```
system %{cmd /c "start #{file_to_open}"}
```

### Linux/Unix Gnome

Use the Gnome utility `gnome-open`:

```
system %{gnome-open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

### Linux/Unix

Use the `xdg-open` utility:

```
system %{xdg-open "#{file_to_open}"}
```